# How to set up an internal domain with Route53 on AWS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, internal-dns, amazon-route53

I have a VPC on Amazon. Currently, it's running `bind9` on one of the servers. It has records like this:

```
build           IN      A       172.aa.bb.cc
dev             IN      A       172.xx.yy.zz
```

This works fine, but in the interest of simplicity, I want to move its functionality to Amazon's Route53.

I've created a Private Hosted Zone on `mydomain.local`. I imported the `db.mydomain.local` file from bind9, and it created a few DNS records that look good to me. I noticed my records are added with the `mydomain.local` suffix, and I'd like them to still be available as shorthand (`dev` rather than `dev.mydomain.local`)

Next, I wanted to test if my configuration actually works. I stopped the bind9 service, and tried some `nslookup` commands, but those didn't seem to pick up the new config.

So, I have a few questions:

- Do I need to configure something on my server(s) to pick up the Route53 config?
- What is the easiest way to test this? I'm not at all familiar with `nslookup` or `dig`.

Any links to helpful documentation are also appreciated. I already read through Amazon's own documentation, but it doesn't seem to cover anything beyond creating the Private Hosted Zone itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you need to configure this in your VPC settings. Go to Services > VPC > DHCP Options Set and select the set with `domain-name-servers = AmazonProvidedDNS`.

Comment: this is also helpful, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html?shortFooter=true#AmazonDNS

Answer (score 2):

Check what is the DNS server that is configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` file. This could be your old bind9 server. If your nodes are using DHCP then you might need to configure this in your DHCP server.

Regarding the short cut usage of `dev` for `dev.mydomain.local` you need to add `search` directive to `resolv.conf`

```
search mydomain.local
```

Once the `search` directive is added any host that is not FQDN will be tried resolving by adding the domain name at last. And so `dev` will be resolved as `dev.mydomain.local`.

Regarding the method to test this issue use `dig`. To check if Route53 is works fine you can specifically query Route53 delegation servers with `@`.

```
$ dig dev.mydomain.local @ns-1216.awsdns-24.org
```

Above command will query for `dev.mydomain.local` with `ns-1216.awsdns-24.org` DNS server. If you dont specify a `@` option then the DNS provided in `/etc/resolv.conf` will be used for querying.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! This answers at least the shorthand from the search command, which is already in the config file you mentioned. It also contains a line `nameserver <IP of bind9 server>`, and a comment saying it shouldn't be edited manually. The `dig` command says `couldn't get address for 'ns-1024.awsdns-00.org.': not found` if the `bind9` service isn't running. I used the address that's configured in the NS record of my Route53 config.

Comment: If your nodes are using DHCP for IP address then you have configure DNS there. I am not sure about which nameserver you should be using for your network please refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html.

Comment: In terms of configuring DHCP, I added this "domain-name = eu-west-1.compute.internal zorotools.local
domain-name-servers = AmazonProvidedDNS" on VPC's DHCP Options sets. Still short cut usage of dev for dev.mydomain.local does not work. It only works only after updating the record on /etc/resolv.conf.  But I don't want to do this manually and it also states on this file "#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN".